# Is there way to group the column in mysql in 3 categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question regarding on my script, If i use the group by the output that I want to get is wrong, however if I  remove the group by statement the output is correct but the grouping of 3 categories multiples times shown

**I want the output look likes this:.**

**Ex.**

[image: I want this to be my output]

**My Output:**

[image: my output]

**My Script:**

```
    SELECT store,

CASE priority_level
WHEN '3' THEN 'High Priority'
WHEN '2' THEN 'Medium Priority'
WHEN '1' THEN 'Low Priority'
END as priority_level,


CAST(CASE priority_level 
WHEN '3' THEN IF(date_received >= DATE_SUB(date_finished,INTERVAL 8 HOUR),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM is_mr_done as imd 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT mr_no,priority_level FROM repair_history ) rh 
ON imd.mr_no = rh.mr_no 
WHERE is_done = '1'  AND rh.priority_level = '3'),'0')

WHEN '2' THEN IF(date_received >= DATE_SUB(date_finished,INTERVAL 3 DAY),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM is_mr_done as imd 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT mr_no,priority_level FROM repair_history ) rh 
ON imd.mr_no = rh.mr_no 
WHERE is_done = '1' AND rh.priority_level = '2'),'0')

WHEN '1' THEN IF(date_received >= DATE_SUB(date_finished,INTERVAL 5 DAY),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM is_mr_done as imd 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT mr_no,priority_level FROM repair_history ) rh 
ON imd.mr_no = rh.mr_no 
WHERE is_done = '1'  AND rh.priority_level = '1'),'0')

END AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) as total_hit,


CASE priority_level 
WHEN '3' THEN IF(date_received >= DATE_SUB(date_finished,INTERVAL 8 HOUR),CONCAT(ROUND((100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM repair_history WHERE priority_level ='3' AND store ='1130') * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM is_mr_done as imd 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT mr_no,priority_level FROM repair_history) rh 
ON imd.mr_no = rh.mr_no 
WHERE is_done = '1'  AND rh.priority_level = '3'))),'%'),'0')




WHEN '2' THEN IF(date_received >= DATE_SUB(date_finished,INTERVAL 3 DAY),CONCAT(ROUND((100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM repair_history WHERE priority_level ='2' ) * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM is_mr_done as imd 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT mr_no,priority_level FROM repair_history) rh 
ON imd.mr_no = rh.mr_no 
WHERE is_done = '1'  AND rh.priority_level = '2'))),'%'),'0')




WHEN '1' THEN IF(date_received >= DATE_SUB(date_finished,INTERVAL 5 DAY),CONCAT(ROUND((100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM repair_history WHERE priority_level ='1' ) * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM is_mr_done as imd 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT mr_no,priority_level FROM repair_history) rh 
ON imd.mr_no = rh.mr_no 
WHERE is_done = '1'  AND rh.priority_level = '1'))),'%'),'0')

END as total_hit_average


FROM repair_history as rh
LEFT JOIN (SELECT mr_no,is_done,date_finished FROM is_mr_done) imd 
ON rh.mr_no = imd.mr_no
WHERE  priority_level  != ''
```

**Table Repair History:**

[image: Table 1]

**Table mr_is_done:**

[image: Table 2]

Comment: It might help if you add columns to the expected output. I can't see how you're getting to those values.

Comment: sure I will add more details

Comment: Please see the new update  thanks

Comment: In your expected output, what are the extra columns? How are the calculated (in simple terms)?

Comment: You could do a simple union to three queries, one for each priority level. This could remove a lot of your case statements, and greatly simplify your query.

Comment: What are the columns of your desired output? Text does not mention calculation of *three categories*. By the way, use derived tables aggregate joins to avoid repetitive subquery logic. See this simpler (untested) rewrite of code: https://pastebin.com/z0L83M00.